# Nested Hash Via Recursion in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

I've been trying to make a nested default hash programmatically in Ruby, basically a short-hand for Ruby's :

```
h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new}
```

I'd like to extend this to work to as many levels as needed. I made the following function:

```
def nested_hash(level, default={})
   return default if level == 0
   return Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = nested_hash(level - 1, default) }
end
```

It looks like it's working correctly but I run into the following issue when creating multiple keys

```
h = nested_hash(1)
h[0][1] = [1, 2, 3] # h is {0=>{1=>[1, 2, 3]}}
h[2] # should give a new Hash, but returns {1=>[1, 2, 3]}
h # {0=>{1=>[1, 2, 3]}, 2=>{1=>[1, 2, 3]}}
```

Why is the default value changing for the function and becoming the previously set value?

**EDIT**

I've found a solution that works:

```
def nested_hash(level, default={})
    return Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = default } if level <= 1
    Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = nested_hash(level - 1, default) }
end
```

Never mind, this doesn't work either in a similar way:

```
h = nested_hash(1)
h[0][1] = [1, 2, 3]
h[2][0] # nil
h # {0=>{1=>[1, 2, 3]}, 2=>{1=>[1, 2, 3]}}
```

I'm still confused as to why the original default was shared amongst the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just out of curiosity:

```
hash =
  Hash.new do |h, k|
    h[k] = h.dup.clear.extend(Module.new do
      define_method(:level, ->{ h.level - 1 })
    end).tap { |this| raise "" if this.level <= 0 }
  end.extend(Module.new { define_method(:level, ->{ 5 }) })

#⇒ {}

hash["0"]["1"]["2"]["3"]
#⇒ {}
hash["0"]["1"]["2"]["3"]["4"]
#⇒ RuntimeError: ""
```

---

Or, as a function:

```
def nhash lvl
  Hash.new do |h, k|
    h[k] = h.dup.clear.extend(Module.new do
      define_method(:level, ->{ h.level - 1 })
    end).tap { |this| raise "" if this.level < 0 }
  end.extend(Module.new { define_method(:level, ->{ lvl }) })
end
```

Resulting in:

```
✎ h = nhash 2
#⇒ {}
✎ h[0][1] = [1, 2, 3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
✎ h[2][0]
#⇒ {}
✎ h[2][0][5]
#⇒ RuntimeError:
```

One might reset the default proc instead of raising if necessary.

The only drawback of this approach, on attempt to call the level above permitted, all the intermediate empty hashes will be created. This *also* might be overcome by defining the method, accumulating the path (instead of simply returning the level,) and erasing empty parents before raising.

Comment: Great answer. Though I'm left wondering why `h.dup.clear` is needed instead of just a new empty hash?

Comment: Oh, maybe to inherit the dynamic `:level` method? Very interesting approach :D

Comment: Can we extend this to have a default value? Ideally, I wanted this to work with an empty array as a key as well. Something like `h = nhash(2, [])` where I can do `h[0][1] << 1` afterwards. Or even something like `h = nhash(2, 0)`, where I can do `h[0][1] += 1`

Comment: “Can we extend [...]?”—Sure you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) for this. The best explanation is that given in the docs:

> If Hash::new was invoked with a block, return that block, otherwise return nil.

So in this case, each new hash key is instantiated with its parent hash's default.

For example:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

That way, every nested level will have the same default:

```
hash[0][1] = [1, 2, 3]
hash[:first_level] # => {}
hash[:first_level][:second_level] # => {}
hash[2] # => {}
hash # => {0=>{1=>[1, 2, 3]}, :first_level=>{:second_level=>{}}, 2=>{}}
```

---

Edit based on comment:

In that case, you could use something ugly, though working, like this:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = raise('Too Deep') } } }
hash[1] # => {}
hash[1][2] # => {}
hash[1][2][3] # => RuntimeError: Too Deep
```

Comment: This is indeed very cool, but I'd like to have a hard cut-off for the levels. `hash[0][1][2][3]` gives an empty hash, whereas I'd like to have it give an error.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Abundance - got led astray by "I'd like to extend this to work to as many levels as needed". See you've reached a nice solution though, glad you've got it going.

Comment: @SRack you might be interested: I slightly extended your idea in my answer to make the length dynamically configured :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AlekseiMatiushkin, that's a _great_ answer you've put together. Glad you dropped this in here or I might have missed it :)